# print the prime factor of an integers in power form ( ^ )

Tags: c++, c, factorial, prime-factoring

I need a program in C++ or C that will calculate prime factor, for Example you input 135 I want an output to be like this (3^3)(5^1) instead of 3,3,3,5.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std; 
void get_divisors(int n); 
int main() 
{
    int n = 0; 
    cout << "Enter a number:";
    cin >> n;
    get_divisors(n);
    cout << endl; 
} 
void get_divisors(int n)
{
     int i;
     double sqrt_of_n = sqrt(n);
     for (i = 2; i <= sqrt_of_n; i++)
         if (n % i == 0) 
         {
            cout << i << ", "; 
            get_divisors(n / i);
            return; 
                 }
     cout << n;
 }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::map<int, int>` to contain the prime number (first integer) and the number of occurances of that prime number (second integer).

So when you have a prime, find the value in the map and if it is not in the map, insert it.

If the prime already exists, increment the count.

When printing, you iterate through the map, printing the prime number, then the '^' character, then the count of primes.

Details left as an exercise for the reader.